# Тень под toolbar

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

Меня интересует как добавить тень под toolbar, чтобы тень выглядела так же как и в actionbar, а то по умолчанию в toolbar нету тени.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: атрибут `elavation` в xml

Comment: попробуйте обернуть `Toolbar` в `AppBarLayout`

Answer (score 1):

For 5.0 + : Ты можешь обернуть toolbar в AppbarLayout. Там есть атрибут elevation

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```